# Excel to Json Python file

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

I am trying to run this python file but it won't give me the JSON file (data.json). I am not sure if I need to specify it more where and how to put it out.

```py
import xlrd 
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
excel_file_path = 'checks.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook (excel_file_path)
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
data_list = []
for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
    data = OrderedDict ()
    row_values = sh.row_values (rownum)
    data ['Code'] = row_values[0]
    data ['Name'] = row_values[1]
    data ['Amount'] = row_values[2]
    data ['Date'] = row_values[3]
    data ['MailingAddress'] = row_values[4]
    data ['MailingAddress2'] = row_values[5]
    data ['MailingCity'] = row_values[6]
    data ['MailingState'] = row_values[7]
    data ['MailingZip'] = row_values[8]
    data_list.append(data)


j = json.dumps (data_list, ensure_ascii = False)

with open('data.json', 'w+') as f:
f.write(j)
```

Comment: Why are you using xlrd? It's unmaintained, and should only be used if necessary when dealing with the old XLS format. What does _it won't give me the JSON file (data.json)_ mean?

Comment: When i run the python script it does not provide me with the json file and i do not see any error. What alternative do i have besides using the xlrd? Thanks